# Better way to handle CORS invalid origin in Express?

Tags: javascript, express, cors

I have this code in my Express back-end:

```js
router.use(
  cors({
    origin(origin, callback) {
      if (
        !origin ||
        /^http:\/\/localhost:8080/.test(origin) ||
        /^https:\/\/.*\.mysite\.com$/.test(origin)
      ) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    },
    credentials: true,
  }),
);
```

The problem with this is that it simply throws an error, resulting in a vague HTTP 500 "Internal server error" for the client. Is there any way to instead use `res` to give a proper response?

Comment: @timotgl The code is valid; it's using [ES2015 shorthand syntax for methods in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions).

Comment: @HereticMonkey You're right, I stand corrected. First time I ever saw this used.

Comment: Note that you can use a regex or an array of regexes for the value of `origin`, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options), if you want a workaround...

Comment: @ffxsam The error code is not what I'd expect as response for the preflight request from the browser. After searching through github issues on the express/cors a bit, I have the feeling you're not meant to send a custom response - the middleware automates that away in the standard way apparently. Is there possibly a different exception that you didn't intend to happen that causes the 500? It's certainly not an internal server error if the request is just rejected.

Comment: Not sure what's up with the unnecessary down-vote. That code example of using callback() to throw an Error is directly from the instructions on the cors npmjs page.

@timotgl I'm definitely getting HTTP 500 "Internal Server Error". The documentation isn't really clear what the first argument of `callback()` is supposed to be. I'd prefer returning an HTTP 403 with a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the documentation's recommendation of passing an error as the first argument of `callback` is not a great idea, as it results in an HTTP 500 error.

Instead, I've modified my code accordingly:

```js
router.use(
  cors({
    origin(origin, callback) {
      if (
        !origin ||
        /^http:\/\/localhost:8080/.test(origin) ||
        /^https:\/\/.*\.mysite\.com$/.test(origin)
      ) {
        callback(null, origin);
      } else {
        callback(null, 'https://app.mysite.com');
      }
    },
    credentials: true,
  }),
);
```

This way the browser will receive the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app.mysite.com` and show a proper CORS error rather than an HTTP 500 error with no details.